# Creating a report for a Sharepoint Online list (helpdesk)

Tags: sharepoint-online, reporting

Recently i created a working helpdesk via Sharepoint Online

Everything is good and all but i now need to come out with some reporting options

I have tried googling but was not able to find a suitable solution

Can anyone please direct me to the right site or tutorial to achieve this?

Edit: Site was developed in Classic Experience as i had to use some scripting to block / hide columns etc

Thanks

Comment: What kind of reports you need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chart web part in modern page --> chart web part. Select your list and it will show reports like bar etc.

Refer this link [Quick chart webpart](https://www.sharepointsky.com/quick-chart-web-part-in-modern-sharepoint-online-site/)

Comment: Hi Monica, i forgotten to mention that my site was created on classic experience as i had to use some script to hide and disable columns etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [PowerBi](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/)? You can connect it to a ton of different data sources such as SharePoint lists and create really neat visuals in an interactive dashboard that updates in real time.

Comment: I did my own research as well and found the PowerBi solution but it seems that for others to view the data they will need the PowerBi Pro license? Trying to find an alternative if possible

Comment: hi Zach, just wondering if you have any experience in the PowerBi solution? For example what will happen if i assign myself the PowerBi Pro license, publish the report on a Sharepoint site and then remove the license? What will happen then?

Comment: I am pretty sure you will need to have the license for Power Bi Pro for it to stick around in the SharePoint site unfortunately. There is an option to publish a Power Bi report to the web but doing so makes it publicly visible. This is a great tool by Microsoft but the licensing for this product doesn't make much sense.